# Value for date input not displayed when using localization, formtastic and activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, uidatepicker

I have a model with a column date of type date.

I'm using ui_datepicker-rails3 with activeadmin and in my form I have:

```
form do |f|
    f.inputs do
        f.input :date, :as => :ui_date_picker
    end
end
```

The format of the date is `dd/mm/yy`.

The problem is that after I send the form, if it has errors and the controller renders the `new` view, then the value of the input is ok but I can't see the date inside the input field. For example:

I fill date with `20/08/2012` and I send the form. When it renders back the input is

```
<input class="datepicker ui-date-picker hasDatepicker" id="progress_date" name="progress[date]" type="text" value="28/08/2012">
```

But the input doesn't show the value on screen.

When I send it formatted as `yy-mm-dd` it works fine.

What could it be?

Comment: do you have this in your js file? $(document).ready(function(){
$('input.ui-date-picker').datetimepicker();
});

Comment: I have this: `$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker('option', 'es' );
});` but for some weird reason that's not setting the date format correctly so I had to add this inside the function: `$('input.ui-date-picker').datepicker('option', 'dateFormat', 'dd/mm/yy');`

Answer (score 0):

ActiveAdmin define a custom DatepickerInput which add the `datepicker` class to date fields.

Objects with this class are formatted to `'yy-mm-dd'` by AA.

To avoid this, put this code in an initializer:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Inputs
    class DatepickerInput < ::Formtastic::Inputs::StringInput
      def input_html_options
        super
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It removes the `datepicker` class to date inputs and left them with `ui-date-picker hasDatepicker`.